# What data type single element extracted from entries attribute of Connection object represent in python?

Tags: python

I am not well versed at python at all. I was asked to review someone else's python script that uses `search ldap entries`. Btw - I can't reach out to original developer for some reason and before it is deployed + tested visual code checking is required. With that constraints in mind, allow me to proceed.

```
import ldap3
from ldap3 import Server,Connection, ALL

conn = Connection(....)
conn.search(....)
for entry in conn.entries:
    if (len(entry['cn']) > 0):
        ....
        name = entry['name']
        if name:
           user_name = str(name)
        else:
           user_name = "Bob"
```

First question is `len(entry['cn']) > 0` I like to interpret it as checking the length of characters of returned cn value from ldap e.g. `cn=bob,ou=people,ou=foocomany`. I am pretty sure `entry['cn']` is NOT string type but I don't know what data type it represents. Can you tell me what type it is?

My 2nd + 3rd questions are not directly related to the original question, but plz bear with me asking for them with grace.

My 2nd question is, if that assumption is correct, `entry['cn']` should be converted to string type like `str(entry['cn'])`. Then check its length?

My 3rd question is on `if` stmt. I like to interpret it as `if name is not null` or `if name is not None` in pythonic way. Did I interpret it correctly? If so I should replace it as `if not (name is None)` would work? I googled on it to get that stmt.

Comment: `print (type(entry['cn']))` should result in some useful information. The second question depends on what type it is (and, mind you, forcibly converting it to a string may be destructive). The third question is: "yes".

Comment: Without knowing more about that `Connection` class, it's impossible to determine what type `entry['cn']` is from the given code. `len()` will return the length of any countable object. Given you're dealing with ldap, `entry['cn']` is likely referring to the common name of the particular entry, which may be a string, a list (array), a dictionary (associative array), or an object of some type. usr2564301's suggestion is a good idea if you can run this in a manner you're certain won't affect production environments; otherwise, post more code.

Comment: Hmm, some quick googling, looks like this is most likely the ldap3 library. Give me a second, I'll put together an answer.

Comment: I will surely give a try running `print` to determine what exactly returned type it is. `Connection` class is for accessing ldap v3 compliant directory. Ty all for your suggestions and advice. yes, `Connection` is from ldap3 library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the context and code provided, it looks like this snippet is using the [ldap3](https://pypi.org/project/ldap3/) library.

From the relevant [documentation](https://ldap3.readthedocs.io/searches.html#entries), `conn.entries` should be a list of [`Entry`](https://ldap3.readthedocs.io/ldap3.abstract.entry.html) objects.

This means that `entry['cn']` should be returning an [`Attribute`](https://ldap3.readthedocs.io/ldap3.abstract.attribute.html). Doing a bit of source diving, this appears to just be a fancy list with writable flags. `len(entry['cn']) > 0` ends up calling [this method](https://github.com/cannatag/ldap3/blob/4453dc36154d78a31b2aefc38781cd683c42db8c/ldap3/abstract/attribute.py#L77), which just returns the number of values that attribute has. It being greater than 0 just ensuring that the cn is, in fact, set.